# Custom Selector for TextView inside ListView

Tags: android, android-listview, textview

How to use Custom textColor for TextView inside Custom ListView? What i need is i have my listview with dark gray background. If i select any row. That row should become white and TextView Color should become dark gray. Can anybody give me snippet or lead me to some nice tutorial?
I tried this. Below is my custom row for ListView

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/list_selector" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/rowListTextView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingBottom="10dp"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:paddingTop="10dp"
        android:text="@string/app_name"
        android:textColor="@color/list_item_text"
        android:textSize="10sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

And this is xml from res/color/ folder

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:state_selected="true" android:color="@color/dark_gray"/>
    <item android:state_focused="true" android:color="@color/dark_gray"/>
    <item android:state_pressed="true" android:color="@color/dark_gray"/>
    <item android:color="@color/white"/>

</selector>
```

It doesnt workout for me. I am able to set row color to white but i am not able to set text color to gray!
i am new to android. help me with this. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Try this color state list for textColor

```html
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_pressed="true" android:color="#fff"/>
    <item android:state_activated="true" android:color="#fff"/>
    <item android:color="#000" />
</selector>
```

[Android guide](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/color-list-resource.html) does not mention `state_activated` attribute but it works for me.